# How to Update remi repository list?

Tags: centos, php, yum

I am trying to upgrade to php 5.5 using remi repository, My OS is Centos 6.4,  but my problem is

when i run the command

```
 yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php
```

i still see the php version 5.4 only, how do i update my remi-repository to use the latest version ?

When i run the remi version i ger

```
[root]# rpm -q remi-release
remi-release-6.4-1.el6.remi.noarch
```

I tried many commands like

```
yum update
```

but there is no luck for me.

Comment: Edit your question and add the (suitably trimmed) output of your yum command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit below file in vim or nano

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

Change

```
enabled = 0
```

To

```
enabled = 1
```

Comment: The command line switch `--enablerepo=remi,remi-php55` would enable the relevant repos without the need to edit the file surely.